# Modified photo , and how to see original photo

Tags: photoshop

Sorry , i have one question , how to see original photo if I download a modified photo (.jpg) from enthernet . something like this : 
[image]

How to see original photo without blue font  ? Can somebody explain me how to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean recover blacked out parts?

Comment: i mean to see original photo without any modification . it is posible  ?

Comment: i mean i put blue part on this photo , how can i see what is without blue  part . there is hidden text . how can i see it  ?

Comment: Contact the creator of the modified photo and ask for an unmodified copy...? Really, what's gone is gone and can't be recovered. There are ways to "fake" it - replacing the letters with an approximation based on surrounding patterns, but there's no way to recover the original content.

Comment: If you put the blue part on this image, and you want to see what is underneath, you have to go back to the original file. If you saved over the original file, then I am afraid it's not possible to do what you want to do. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Some image file formats support "layers", where it is possible to overlay something on a lower layer, with that overlaid portion being recoverable in the future. Adobe Photoshop's PSD format is an example of a file format that supports layers.

However, other image file formats simply do not support layers. They essentially have just one layer. If something is overlaid on the image, and the file is saved, then whatever was covered is gone for good. The JPEG format does not support layers.